# Does exchange or compare_and_exchange reads last value in modification order?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, lock-free, memory-model

I am reading [C++ Concurrency in Action](http://www.manning.com/williams/) by Anthony Williams.
At section "Understanding Relaxed Ordering" it has:

> There are a few additional things you can tell the man in the cubicle, such as “write down this number, and tell me what **was at the bottom of the list**” (exchange) and “write down
>   this number if the number **on the bottom of the list** is that; otherwise tell me what I
>   should have guessed” (compare_exchange_strong), but that doesn’t affect the general
>   principle.

Does it mean that such operations always read last value in modification order (if there are no additional inter-thread happens before constraints)? I.e. are there some caches updates/etc (even in relaxed ordering)?

Comment: "_read last value_" last compared to what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. The C++ Standard says (29.3/10):

> Atomic read-modify-write operations shall always read the last value
>   (in the modification order) written before the write associated with
>   the read-modify-write operation.

Both `exchange` and successful `compare_exchange_{weak,strong}` operations are read-modify-write operations.