# Confusion about C++11 lock free stack push() function

Tags: multithreading, c++11, concurrency

I'm reading C++ Concurrency in Action by Anthony Williams, and don't understand its push implementation of the `lock_free_stack` class. Listing 7.12 to be precise

```
void push(T const& data)
{
    counted_node_ptr new_node;
    new_node.ptr=new node(data);
    new_node.external_count=1;
    new_node.ptr->next=head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) 
    while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node.ptr->next,new_node, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
}
```

So imagine 2 threads (`A`, `B`) calling push function. Both of them reach while loop but not start it. So they both read the same value from `head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)`.

Then we have the following things going on:

1. `B` thread gets swiped out for any reason
2. `A` thread starts the loop and obviously successfully adds a new node to the stack.
3. `B` thread gets back on track and also starts the loop.

And this is where it gets interesting as it seems to me.
Because there was a **load** operation with `std::memory_order_relaxed` and `compare_exchange_weak(..., std::memory_order_release, ...)` in case of success it looks like there is no synchronization between threads whatsoever.
I mean it's like `std::memory_order_relaxed - std::memory_order_release` **and not** `std::memory_order_acquire - std::memory_order_release`.

So `B` thread will simply add a new node to the stack but to its initial state when we had no nodes in the stack and reset head to this new node.

I was doing my research all around this subject and the best i could find was in this post [Does exchange or compare_and_exchange reads last value in modification order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795126/does-exchange-or-compare-and-exchange-reads-last-value-in-modification-order)

So the question is, is it true? and all RMW functions see the last value in modification order? No matter what `std::memory_order` we used, if we use RMW operation it will synchronize with all threads (CPU and etc) and find the last value to be written to the atomic operation upon it is called?

Answer (score 0):

So after some research and asking a bunch of people I believe I found the proper answer to this question, I hope it'll be a help to someone.

> So the question is, is it true? and all RMW functions see the last
>   value in modification order?

Yes, it is true.

> No matter what std::memory_order we used, if we use RMW operation it
>   will synchronize with all threads (CPU and etc) and find the last
>   value to be written to the atomic operation upon it is called?

Yes, it is also true, however there is something that needs to be highlighted.

RMW operation will synchronize **only the atomic variable it works with**. In our case, it is **head.load**

Perhaps you would like to ask why we need release - acquire semantics at all if RMW does the synchronization even with the relaxed memory order.

The answer is because RMW works only with the variable it synchronizes, but other operations which occurred before RMW might not be seen in the other thread.

lets look at the push function again:

```
void push(T const& data)
{
    counted_node_ptr new_node;
    new_node.ptr=new node(data);
    new_node.external_count=1;
    new_node.ptr->next=head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) 
    while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node.ptr->next,new_node, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
}
```

In this example, in case of using two push threads they won't be synchronized with each other to some extent, but it could be allowed here.

Both threads will always see the newest head because `compare_exchange_weak`
provides this. And a new node will be always added to the top of the stack.
However if we tried to get the value like this `*(new_node.ptr->next)` after this line `new_node.ptr->next=head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` things could easily turn ugly: **empty pointer might be dereferenced**. 
This might happen because a processor can change the order of instructions and because there is no synchronization between threads the second thread could see the pointer to a top node even before that was initialized!

And this is exactly where release-acquire semantic comes to help. It ensures that all operations which happened before release operation will be seen in acquire part!
*Check out and compare listings 5.5 and 5.8 in the book.*

I also recommend you to read this article about how processors work, it might provide some essential information for better understanding.
[memory barriers](http://www.rdrop.com/users/paulmck/scalability/paper/whymb.2010.07.23a.pdf)